# Appending two lists mutually to each other gives unexpected results containing "[...]"

Tags: python, list, append, recursive-datastructures

I have 2 lists:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [9, 8, 7]
```

I performed the following two operations and tried printing each list

```
a.append(b)
b.append(a)
print(a) # Expected Result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [9, 8, 7]]
print(b) # Expected Result: [9, 8, 7, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

But the result turned out to be:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [9, 8, 7, [...]]]
b = [9, 8, 7, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [...]]]
```

Can someone explain in detail what exactly is happening here?

I tried printing each element of the list but the list keep on going without any end.

Comment: Can you see how `a.append(b.copy())` and `b.append(a.copy())` would behave differently from `a.append(b)` and `b.append(a)` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python lists are stored by references. You add such reference to the lists, which can be **still** modified in another place. After `a.append(b)` you've got `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, b]`. That b has value `[9,8,7]` **at the moment**, but when you `b.append(a)`, you change the value of it to `[9, 8, 7, a]`. And that `a` happens to contain `b`, and so on ending up with cycle of two lists contained in each other. If you want to avoid that, you need to make a *copy* of list you want to append. A copy will make it so changes to original list are not reflected in the copy.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [9,8,7]

a_copy = a.copy()
b_copy = b.copy()

a.append(b_copy)
b.append(a_copy)

print(a) # Expected Result: [1,2,3,4,5,[9,8,7]]
print(b) # Expected Result: [9, 8, 7 ,[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you append one list to another, you are not creating a copy of the list, but rather adding a reference to the original list. This means that if you modify the original list, the changes will be reflected in the appended list as well, and vice versa.

You create a circular reference where list `a` contains a reference to list `b`, and list `b` contains a reference to list `a`. This is why when you print the lists, you see nested lists

if you try using `a.copy()` and `b.copy()` then you'll get your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create both lists in the same time. This will create two new lists when both are evaluated before the assignment

```
a, b = a + [b], b + [a]

# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [9, 8, 7]]
# [9, 8, 7, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```